# How to implement add 'load more' on this page?

Tags: javascript

What i would want is to display, say, 10 job list, and then for the rest of them to have a "Load More" button or something like function.

Please see the script bellow:

```
    <!-- Listings -->
                <div class="title-bordered">
                    <h2>Our Professionals <small>Latest added</small></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="job_listings">
                    <ul class="job_listings">
                        <li class="job_listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="job_img">
                                    <img src="images/samples/person1.jpg" alt="" class="company_logo">
                                </div>
                                <div class="position">
                                    <h3>Debbie Bidart</h3>
                                    <div class="company">
                                        <strong>Paint Removal from Exterior or Interior Surfaces</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="location">
                                    <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Melbourne, AU
                                </div>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <div class="rating-stars">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reviews-num">12 Reviews</div>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="meta">
                                    <li class="job-type">Painting</li>
                                    <li class="date">
                                        Posted 1 month ago
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                <div class="spacer"></div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" href="#">View All Professionals</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Listings / End -->
```

I need that functionality implemented there. I'm assuming it should not be hard to do, but, I'm not sure what i'm doing.

I Hope someone can help. Thankx.

Comment: can you give us a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi Naxis That's the problem i don't have it. it's a script only in html i would like to know if it can be done with java-script. and how to make this simple html work in full function, thanx.

Comment: Shall i send a link to the page to get a more clear understanding,

Comment: You need something like https://codepen.io/Tigran_91/pen/JyaZPz ?

Comment: Yes exactly but the think is i tried some of those on codepen, and i had a problem in implementing those scripts into the one posted as you can tell i'm not very good at this, if you can help well appreciated.

Comment: is it possible to send a snap shot of what i mean?